# Why doesn't ViewComponent class have an abstract definition for Invoke method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am wondering why didn't Microsoft define an abstract method `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` in `ViewComponent` abstract class, when `Invoke` method is essential for view component to work?

Is there any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just design decision. When you invoke view component - you can pass arbitrary number of arguments, with arbitrary types. All those arguments will be passed to `InvokeAsync` method. To not pack them in something like `object[]` array - it's allowed to define `InvokeAsync` method with any number of strongly typed arguments:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(int arg1, string arg2) {
    // ...
}
```

During invocation, methods of your ViewComponent will be inspected via reflection and one with correct signature for this invocation will be chosen. Because of this (arbitrary parameters for `InvokeAsync`) - it is not possible to declare this method abstract (or virtual).

You can see the same design in other places too, for example `Startup` class can have method with name `Configure` which takes arbitrary number of arguments, and those arguments will be resolved from DI container, but Startup class does not override any methods in parent class (actually there is no parent class at all in this case).